# CMake install can't find library and points to wrong compiler version

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, redhat

linux noob here- will appreciate any kind of help.

**Some background:**

I'm trying to build a program from source on RHEL 6.5, the dependencies for this program are specifically:

- GCC 4.7 and above (for C++ 11 support)
- CMake 2.8.9+

we already had GCC 4.4.7 installed in /usr/libexec/gcc, so our linux person built and installed the new version in /usr/local/libexec/gcc (version 4.9)

We didn't have CMake so I installed in from scratch by unizipping the source in /usr/local and following the directions from here:
http://www.cmake.org/install/

./bootstrap
  make
  make install

so far so good and in the CMakeOutput.log of the CMake it is correctly pointing to the new GCC's path, [COMPILER PATH=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/.../4.9.2/

and I did have to copy a .so file from /usr/lib64 to /usr/local/lib64 in order to successfully bootstrap/make it but I don't think that's the source of my problem.

**The Problem:**

Now here's what i'm having trouble with: so when I finally try to build this program using "cmake ."

I get the following issues:

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7

-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Failed

The compiler identification should be version 4.9 and the Test should've succeeded but it did not...

-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)

-- Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG INCLUDE_ DIR)

Cmake has the FindPNG cmake module file in /usr/local/cmake-3.0.2/Modules but it doesn't seem to know where it is, I tried copying just the FindPNG.cmake file into the local cmake directory of the program and I just kept getting missing module files one after another...

Now- I think all these errors could just be a result of something not pointing to something correctly, maybe not setting environment variables for something, missing or wrong CMake commands / variables in the CMakeList file or whatever but I have spent a quite amount of time trying to fix it trying different approaches but just couldn't figure it out...any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Here's the top level CMakeLists.txt of the program I'm trying to build:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(COLLADA2GLTF)

if (NOT WIN32)
#http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/01/05/enabling-c11-c0x-in-cmake/
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    message("-- C++11 Enabled")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
    message("-- C++0x Enabled")
else()
        message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()
endif()

set(USE_OPEN3DGC "ON")
set(WITH_IN_SOURCE_BUILD "ON")
set(COLLADA2GLTF_BINARY_DIR, COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "OFF")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
get_git_head_revision(GIT_REFSPEC GIT_SHA1)

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp" @ONLY)

set(TARGET_LIBS GeneratedSaxParser_static OpenCOLLADABaseUtils_static UTF_static ftoa_static MathMLSolver_static OpenCOLLADASaxFrameworkLoader_static OpenCOLLADAFramework_static buffer_static)

if (NOT WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .so .a .dylib)
endif()

# Lets libxml2 work in a shared library
add_definitions(-DLIBXML_STATIC_FOR_DLL)

IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "x86_64") 
 ADD_DEFINITIONS(-fPIC) 
ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "x86_64")

include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR})
.......
include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/OpenCOLLADA/COLLADABaseUtils/include)
include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/OpenCOLLADA/COLLADASaxFrameworkLoader/include)
include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/OpenCOLLADA/GeneratedSaxParser/include)
if (WIN32)
    include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/misc)
endif()

if (USE_OPEN3DGC)
    add_definitions( -DUSE_OPEN3DGC )
    include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/extensions/o3dgc-compression)

    include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/o3dgc/src)
    include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/o3dgc/src/o3dgc_common_lib/inc)
    include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/o3dgc/src/o3dgc_encode_lib/inc)
    include_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/o3dgc/src/o3dgc_decode_lib/inc)
endif()

find_package(PNG)
if (PNG_FOUND)
    include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
    add_definitions(-DUSE_LIBPNG)
else()
    message(WARNING "libpng or one of its dependencies couldn't be found. Transparency may not be correctly detected.")
endif()

link_directories(${COLLADA2GLTF_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

if (WIN32)
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
    add_definitions(-DWIN32)
    add_definitions(-EHsc)
endif()

add_subdirectory(dependencies/OpenCOLLADA)

if (USE_OPEN3DGC)
    add_subdirectory(dependencies/o3dgc/src)
endif()

set(GLTF_SOURCES
    COLLADA2GLTFWriter.h
    COLLADA2GLTFWriter.cpp
    ......
    assetModifiers/GLTFFlipUVModifier.cpp

    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp
    GitSHA1.h)

if (USE_OPEN3DGC)
LIST(APPEND GLTF_SOURCES
    extensions/o3dgc-compression/GLTF-Open3DGC.cpp
    extensions/o3dgc-compression/GLTF-Open3DGC.h)
endif()

option(CONVERT_SHARED "CONVERT_SHARED" OFF)
if (CONVERT_SHARED)
    add_library(collada2gltfConvert SHARED ${GLTF_SOURCES})
    #Make sure the dll is in the same directory as the executable
    if (WIN32)
        set_target_properties(collada2gltfConvert PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "bin")
    endif()
else()
    add_library(collada2gltfConvert STATIC ${GLTF_SOURCES})
    add_definitions(-DSTATIC_COLLADA2GLTF)
endif()

if (PNG_FOUND)
    LIST(APPEND TARGET_LIBS ${PNG_LIBRARY} ${ZLIB_LIBRARY})
endif()

if (USE_OPEN3DGC)
LIST(APPEND TARGET_LIBS o3dgc_common_lib o3dgc_enc_lib o3dgc_dec_lib)
endif()

IF("${CMAKE_SYSTEM}" MATCHES "Linux")
    LIST(APPEND TARGET_LIBS rt)
endif("${CMAKE_SYSTEM}" MATCHES "Linux")

target_link_libraries (collada2gltfConvert ${TARGET_LIBS})

set(GLTF_EXE_SOURCES  main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp
    GitSHA1.h)

if (WIN32)
LIST(APPEND GLTF_EXE_SOURCES ${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/misc/getopt_long.c ${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/misc/getopt.c ${COLLADA2GLTF_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/misc/getopt.h)
endif()

add_executable(collada2gltf ${GLTF_EXE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (collada2gltf collada2gltfConvert)
```

Comment: You need http://sscce.org/

Comment: Shortened it a bit- thanks for the suggestion

Comment: As you are seeing multiple issues, I recommend an sscce for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're just facing the problem of unsatisfied dependencies. RHEL/CentOS 6 is pretty old distribution with an old kernel and applications; its recent releases are distributed with deprecated packages (like in your case) due to the needs of the backward compatibility. So is there any significant reason for you to use the one?

I spend one year in the project where we were developing software under RHEL 6.4 and I would suggest that you set yourself an impossible goal: you need to install to your OS not just a compiler, but also all of its libraries (for instance, actual C++ standard library .so etc.) and headers.  Since these versions are not provided in you distro, you'll face difficulties due to the presence of same but differing libraries. Since all system software relies on to the old libraries, your manipulation can crash your system.

However, in case if you want to continue, you can try to install missing dependencies `ZLIB` and `PNG` with these commands (just a suggestion):
`yum install zlib-devel libpng-devel`

But definitly I would suggest you to save your time and deploy some fresh distro: CentOS 7 (if you want server) or Fedora 21 (will be released tommorow).

Comment: Hey Vitaly, thanks for reading my post- and unfortunately, I have to stick to RHEL 6.5 due to project requirements.... i understand your concerns but we're not doing significant development on top of this, just need this program built so hopefully we'll be okay ... and also- I forgot to mention ZLIB and LIBPNG seems to be already installed, so CMake just seems to not be able to point to the correct path for something....

Comment: I was in the same situation: RHEL 6.4 restrictions forced me to give up the most of C++11 features. Probably you should look towards a full-featured `chroot` environment where you can manually install all dependencies and substitute the compiler (on the same path `/usr/libexec/gcc`). But it is possible that you will have to first build a compiler from source... Good luck anyway)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I had a whole different issue with pointing to the wrong paths which was causing this issue in the first place but reinstalling the libraries w yum install zlib-devel libpng-devel did fix the error regarding the dependencies so I'm marking Vitaly's answer as the correct one.